# Smaller embedding size causes lower loss

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer, tokenization

When I convert my multilingual transformer model to a single lingual transformer model (got my languages embedding from the multilingual transformer and deleted other embeddings, decreased dimensions of embedding layers), the loss is much less. But I didn't understand why. What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### New Answer

The loss of a text generation task like question generation is normally the average categorical cross-entropy of the output at every time step.

Drastically reducing the number of tokens means that the number of classes of the output probability distribution is greatly reduced.

The value of cross-entropy depends on the number of classes. Having more classes means that the output distribution must cover more options and it is more difficult to assign more probability to the ground truth class (i.e. the correct token).

Therefore, it is to be expected that, if you drastically reduce the number of tokens, the value of the loss is lower.

#### Old answer

From your description, I understand that:

- What you had was a Transformer trained on multilingual data with word-level tokens (because if you had subword-level tokens like BPE or unigram then you would not be able to filter by language from the token list so easily).
- What you did was:

  - Removing the entries associated with words in other languages from the token list.
  - Reduce the embedding size.
  - Retrain your model on the data of a single language pair.

With those assumptions:

When you "converted your model from multilingual to single lingual", you simplified the task enormously. It seems that the gain in the simplicity of the task surpassed the loss of capacity of the model caused by the reduction of the embedding size.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but how i did that was like this: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-adapt-a-multilingual-t5-model-for-a-single-language-b9f94f3d9c90, I am using sentence piece tokenization. With the method that i provided i converted the multilingual model and tokenizer to a single language model and tokenizer. Is this method that blog says wrong, or does it have bad effects?

Comment: But still, i guess your answer is still valid right?

Comment: In the post, they only select tokens from English and Russian, but they do not change the embedding size nor retrain the model. Did you retrain T5 from scratch after changing the embedding size? Which what loss are you comparing the reduced model's loss?

Comment: They do change the embedding size of the model. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQnMg.png ,, I fine-tuned T5 from pre-trained T5 after converting multilingual to single language operation and compared it with multilingual T5(same pretrained model). And used loss function is "The negative log likelihood loss."

Comment: I see the misunderstanding. "Embedding size" is normally used to refer to the dimensionality of the embedding, not the number of elements in the embedding table. What they are changing is the number of elements in the embedding table. We were speaking about different things.

Comment: Ohhh i see, very good point. So can this be the reason why loss is converges to "low" much faster?

Comment: It is not clear to me what loss you are referring to. They are not retraining the model. Are you? On what data? And what are you comparing the loss with?

Comment: I am using T5 for question generation. Because of i dont have pre-trained T5 tokenizer and model for my language, i trained multilingual T5 model for the "question generation" task with my language's data. But when i apply this operation that i linked to you, my loss function is decreasing very fast(also loss function is starting low).  // I am using huggingface trainer and since i didnt specify any loss function, probably default loss function is being used which is : https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/8e8384663d716d4b5a4f510070ff954fc0ba4a52/src/transformers/trainer.py#L2492

Comment: Of course, i retrained data after operations that i linked. And compared losses with multilingual model's losses

Comment: I edited the answer with this new information.

Comment: Next time, please include all this information in the original question. This will save you and the people answering your question a lot of wasted time due to attempting to answer without enough context.

Comment: You are right, my bad. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, one more question about this topic. Do you think will decrease of embedding size will cause higher accuracy too? Because of decreased complexity or something? Because in cross-entropy loss accuracy and loss may be inversely proportional.

Comment: Decreasing the number of vectors, like you are doing, may or may not change the accuracy. Only actual testing can tell.

Comment: I actually tested and accuracy went high, i just dont know why accuracy increased. I totally understood why loss is lower but i dont know why did accuracy increased. Do you have any opinion?

Comment: No, no opinion.